# Prevent TestInitialize running for one TestMethod method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, attributes

I have a set of unit tests that require `TestInitialize` to run for them to work... however, there is one specific test that i'd love to be able to run without running `TestInitialize`. Is there a way to do that?

It might look like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class BingBangBoom
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        // ...
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Bing()
    {
        // ...
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Bang()
    {
        // ...
    }

    [TestMethod(PreventInitialize)]
    public void Boom
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

No worries if not, I can come up with an alternative solution

**Edit - RE DavidG:**

It seems a shame to have this:

```
[TestClass]
public class BingBangBoom
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        // ...
    }

    // 10 very related methods
}

[TestClass]
public class BingBangBoom2
{
    // 1 method, even though it's entirely related to BingBangBoomin'
}
```

I guess it is what it is.

Comment: Put that test in another class?

Comment: Thanks - @DavidG - I have added an edit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's not immediately obvious, but surely doable.

Assuming you have attribute like this:

```
public class SkipInitializeAttribute : Attribute { }
```

The thing you need is public property inside your test class to be injected by testing framework:

```
public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
```

And then just branch your initialization like this:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    bool skipInitialize = GetType().GetMethod(TestContext.TestName)
        .GetCustomAttributes<SkipInitializeAttribute>().Any();

    if (!skipInitialize)
    {
        // Initialization code here
    }
}
```

Working sample as self-tested solution:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    public class SkipInitializeAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

        private bool IsInitializationDone { get; set; }

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            bool skipInitialize = GetType().GetMethod(TestContext.TestName).GetCustomAttributes<SkipInitializeAttribute>().Any();

            if (!skipInitialize)
            {
                // Initialization code here
                IsInitializationDone = true;
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(IsInitializationDone);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [SkipInitialize]
        public void TestMethod2()
        {
            Assert.IsFalse(IsInitializationDone);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod3()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(IsInitializationDone);
        }
    }
}
```

And results:

```
Starting test execution, please wait...
Passed   TestMethod1
Passed   TestMethod2
Passed   TestMethod3

Total tests: 3. Passed: 3. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
Test Run Successful.
```

Having this general idea in mind you can play with base class / helpers etc.

Comment: Thanks for the custom attribute approach :) Rad!